# Can I inherit from an existing asp.net control from a custom user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, webforms

I want to create my own custom DropDownList control that will function exactly like the asp:DropDownList control, but with a minor tweak to one of its functionalities. Is there a way to do this (like maybe inheritance) without have to wrap it and bubble up every single event from the asp:DropDownList to myCustomControl:DropDownList?

Comment: Yes, you can subclass `DropDownList` and override the various `virtual` methods within. You only need to override the methods you want to. But note that if you only want to change how the control renders HTML (instead of adding new _behaviour_ then look at Control Adapters instead of subclassing: https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/asp-net-web-forms-extensibility-control-adapters)

Comment: Perhaps with a [custom server control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhzc935f.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip writing all methods when you inherit the dropdown control however you have to override at least the Render method

something like that: override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)